# Favourite Open Source Google App Engine apps (Java or Python)

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, open-source

To learn from good examples, what are the best open source Google App Engine applications out there?

I don't care if it is Java or Python based.

Please one app per answer. Feel free to add a link to the live app (if there is) and to the project page.

Comment: That may be useful as a reference http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/web/google-app-engine-open-source-projects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Rietveld](http://codereview.appspot.com/) of course

Comment: +1 nice. a code review tool for the web written by Guido van Rossum

Comment: A couple of days after reading your answer I totally accidentally found myself reading the Rietveld source for guidance. So I had to come back and give you a +1 :)

For the record, it is a good place to see how to make a straight-up Django app on AppEngine (i.e. no app-engine-patch). It is always updated as opposed to the docs (e.g. they are already using Django 1.1).

Comment: Also they have useful middleware to attach the current user to the request using the google user API.

Answer (score 7):

I dearly love my [App Engine Console](http://con.appspot.com/). It is a mini-app, a "plug-in" for other applications. It gives you an AJAX Python interpreter that runs on the server—great for development and debugging. Sometimes I use cURL pointed at App Engine Console to run (authenticated) one-off remote Python procedure calls.

(I wrote it, yes, but I use it daily for maintenance of busy sites. It's the first tool I install on new projects and I don't know how I could live without it.)

Answer (score 3):

UserInfuser, a gamification platform: http://code.google.com/p/userinfuser and https://github.com/nlake44/UserInfuser

It can help you add gamification elements to your website (badges and leaderboards). It uses the Channel API for badge notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Khan Academy. One of App Engine's bigger customers.
https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Repo/Website/Group/stable/Files

Answer (score 2):

[JaikuEngine](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/) is probably Google's biggest open source App Engine project.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [FoFou](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/fofou/index.html) which is a simple forum software that I have used.

FoFou is open source and [hosted on github](http://github.com/kjk/fofou).

Answer (score 1):

[Partychapp](http://code.google.com/p/partychapp/) is a Java GAE app using the XMPP services to allow users to create and join chatrooms together.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Bloog](http://bloog.billkatz.com/), a simple blogging application. [Source is on github](http://github.com/DocSavage/bloog).

Answer (score 1):

OpenShare (http://openshare.emotionull.com)

http://bitbucket.org/jonromero/openshare/src/

Answer (score 1):

[StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) is a webapp that allows printing of StackOverflow's questions in a Printer-Friendly way.
Source code is on [github](http://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter).

Answer (score 1):

[Eezee MVC](http://code.google.com/p/eezeemvc/) is An Easy Model, View, Controller Framework for Google App Engine.
**Features**

Has a Controller Class that does routing, handling and rendering templates.

Your controllers reside in the controllers folder, views (html Django templates) in views folder, models in models folder.

Allows Controller to recieve GET/POST parameters as function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Pubsubhubbub: A simple, open, server-to-server web-hook-based pubsub (publish/subscribe) protocol as an extension to Atom and RSS.

http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/