# Open Source application on GAE/Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, open-source

Is there any Free and Open Source web application which is developed on Google App Engine's Java platform?

Comment: Did you have a look at this SO thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502820/favourite-open-source-google-app-engine-apps-java-or-python What is your question more precisely? [EDIT] Some links about Google App Engine Java apps - [Writing your First Marketplace App using Java](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_java.html) - [Google App Engine for Java tuto](http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html)

Comment: My primary objective is to learn the basics of GAE/Java in a more practical way. So I would like to know about any applications whose source code is available free and which uses GAE/Java as it's platform

Comment: Learning from other's code is quite hard and IMHO, the best way to learn is to practice, practice and... practice. I've edited my answer to add some pointers.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But in some cases you may need to know the best way to do a piece. I'm following the tutorials by GAE team, but I'm still struggling to find the best approach in data modelling and related stuff. The second link you provided seems to be new to me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are many. Here's mine: https://memwords.appspot.com/. Its source code is hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/memwords/). See http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAppEngine for a list of other projects hosted on google code and labeled with *AppEngine*.

Comment: Thanks, I guess memwords is a great app to start with